# intent.getParcelableExtra (NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG) return null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity1. I want to call resolveIntent  method in a class from Activity1 .
when i click on a button in activity1 this code is executed:

```
        Intent IntObj=new Intent();
         IntObj.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);                                                                                                                                                          IntObjputExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG,getIntent().getParcelableExtra
        (NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
            appletcommunication appletclass=new appletcommunication(IntObj);
         if(!appletclass.ReadyConnection)
               return;//nfc communication not erady
```

in class I has this code

```
   public class appletcommunication {

private static final String TAG = null;
//private NfcAdapter mAdapter = null;
static IsoDep myTag;
static  byte AppletCLA=(byte)0x00;
public  static boolean ReadyConnection;


public appletcommunication(Intent intent) {
    resolveIntent( intent);
}


    public  Boolean resolveIntent(Intent intent)
{
 Boolean bresult=true;


     String action = intent.getAction();

      if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action))
      {
        Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        final Tag t = (Tag) tag;
        myTag = IsoDep.get(t);

        if (myTag != null) 
        {
           if (!myTag.isConnected()) 
           {
               try {
                   myTag.connect();
                   myTag.setTimeout(5000);
                    } 
               catch (IOException e)
                  {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   bresult=false;
                  }
          }
          if (myTag.isConnected()) 
          {
               String szATR = null;
               try {

                    szATR = "kkk";
                   } 
               catch (Exception e)
                  {

                   szATR = "CARD DETECTED  ";
                   bresult=false;
                  }
           }

     }
    else
      bresult=false;

      }
    else
         bresult=false;

      return bresult;

}
```

1-but in this line tag is  null.
       Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

Thanks in Advance

Comment: NFC on android needs permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` Look if it helps you.

Comment: 1) if you don't set an action for intObj in Activity1, then getAction() can only return null in Activity2. 2) Sorry but I don't understand what the second problem is. Except maybe that you also have to put extras for the Intent in Activity1 yourself, so you would have to put a Parcelable (some class which implements Parcelable) as extra

Comment: I don't know how to generAte parcelable valu  for nfcadapter.EXTRA_TAG

Answer (score -1):

Please get all methods help about getParcelableExtra from below mentioned URL

http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.content.Intent/getParcelableExtra

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Mumtaz